App quits working after deploying to a build path
I have a strange issue going on that I've poured hours even days trying to dig out a solution as to why it isn't working.
But in essence im using Vite.js and it's VitePWA Plugin to create a PWA, with that in mind im also telling VitePWA to use a custom service worker "sw.js".
When I deploy to my app in vercel on the preview URL the service worker performances great, however, upon deploying to a build path and the app going through build it doesn't seem to work anymore.
It looks like for one the sw.js file is not being rendered as a JS file despite all the other files inside of dist being recognised and actioned as JS files.
I come across the following errors:

Cannot use import outside of a module.

firebase_messaging.js?v=1fdb8c84:670 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
at Component.WindowMessagingFactory [as instanceFactory] (firebase_messaging.js?v=1fdb8c84:670:27)
at Provider.getOrInitializeService (chunk-YSMR3PQH.js?v=1fdb8c84:659:33)
at Provider.getImmediate (chunk-YSMR3PQH.js?v=1fdb8c84:525:21)
at getMessagingInWindow (firebase_messaging.js?v=1fdb8c84:742:61)
at firebase.js:15:20

9cc91927-2951-4e9f-b416-4bf64d48c970:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:5173/') with script ('http://localhost:5173/dev-sw.js?dev-sw'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed


Here is my vite.config.js
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr(), VitePWA(
    {
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      srcDir: 'src',
      filename: 'sw.js',
      injectManifest: {
        rollupFormat: 'iife',
      },
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      includeAssets: ['favicon.ico', 'apple-touch-icon.png', 'mask-icon.svg'],
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true
      },
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg}']
      },
      // Below is the Web App Manifest that is used for the PWA
      manifest: {
        name: 'Redacted',
        short_name: 'Redacted',
        description: 'Redacted App Description',
        theme_color: '#ffffff',
        icons: [
          {
            src: '/public/images/icons/app-icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: '/public/images/icons/app-icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  )],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: ["./vitest-setup.js"],
  },
})

Here is my firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Redacted",
  authDomain: "Redacted",
  projectId: "Redacted",
  storageBucket: "Redacted",
  messagingSenderId: "Redacted",
  appId: "Redacted"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

/**
 * The below should result in a notification appearing upon the app running in the background
 * The title, body and icon can be updated 
*/
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  //console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  
  const notificationTitle = 'Redacted Incident';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: `Incident declared at ${payload?.data?.venuename}. Please log in to the app to access incident details.`,
    icon: 'Redacted'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);

    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
        event.notification.close();
        // Enumerate windows, and call window.focus(), or open a new one.
        clients.openWindow("/incidents/" + payload?.data?.incidentid);

    });
});

And I also have a firebase.js file:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "redacted",
  authDomain: "redacted",
  projectId: "redacted",
  storageBucket: "redacted",
  messagingSenderId: "redacted",
  appId: "redacted"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const  messaging = getMessaging(app);

/** 
 * The below function generates the token for the current device
*/ 

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then((registration) => {
  console.log("Service Worker registered successfully:", registration);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("Service Worker registration failed:", error);
});

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: import.meta.env.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    localStorage.setItem("firebaseToken", currentToken);
  } else {
    //console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    localStorage.removeItem("firebaseToken");
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  //console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  localStorage.removeItem("firebaseToken");
});

export { app, firebaseConfig, messaging };

And last but not least here is my sw.js which is the declared custom worker for my VitePWA:
    import { cacheNames, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'

    //Import routing modules for registering routes and setting default and catch handlers
    import { registerRoute, setCatchHandler, setDefaultHandler } from 'workbox-routing'

    //Import caching modules for caching strategies
    import {
        NetworkFirst, //Cache the network response first and return it if it succeeds, otherwise return the cached response
        NetworkOnly, //Fetch the resource from the network and don't cache it
        Strategy, //Base class for caching strategies
    } from 'workbox-strategies'

    //Firebase
    // declare let firebase: any;
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from 'firebase/messaging/sw';
    import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase';

    const data = {
        race: false, //Fetch first, if it fails, return a previously cached response
        debug: false, //Don't log debug messages for intercepted requests and responses
        credentials: 'same-origin', //Only request resources from the same origin
        networkTimeoutSeconds: 0, //Timout in seconds for network requests; 0 means no timeout
        fallback: 'index.html' //Fallback to index.html if the request fails
    }

    // Access the pre-defined cache names for use in this app
    const cacheName = cacheNames.runtime

    //Configure the strategy for handling all requests based on the data object
    const buildStrategy = () => {

        //If race condition is set to true, begin a race condition between fetching from Network and Cache
        if (data.race) {
            class CacheNetworkRace extends Strategy {

                //Handle method for the race condition exists on the Strategy Calass
                _handle(request, handler) {
                    const fetchAndCachePutDone = handler.fetchAndCachePut(request)
                    const cacheMatchDone = handler.cacheMatch(request)

                    //Return Promise with race conditions where the first to resolve wins
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        fetchAndCachePutDone.then(resolve).catch((e) => {
                            if (data.debug)
                                console.log(`Cannot fetch resource: ${request.url}`, e)
                        })
                        cacheMatchDone.then(response => response && resolve(response))

                        // Reject if both network and cache error or find no response.
                        Promise.allSettled([fetchAndCachePutDone, cacheMatchDone]).then((results) => {
                            const [fetchAndCachePutResult, cacheMatchResult] = results
                            //fetchAndCachePutResult will be rejected if the network request fails and cacheMatchResult will be 
                            //undefined if the cache is empty since the cachematch promise has no way to be rejected
                            if (fetchAndCachePutResult.status === 'rejected' && cacheMatchResult.status !== 'fulfilled')
                                reject(fetchAndCachePutResult.reason)
                        })
                    })

                }
            }
            return new CacheNetworkRace()
        }
        else {
            if (data.networkTimeoutSeconds > 0)
                return new NetworkFirst({ cacheName, networkTimeoutSeconds: data.networkTimeoutSeconds })
            else
                return new NetworkFirst({ cacheName })
        }
    }

    //Retrieve the manifest. First define asynchronus function to retrieve the manifest
    // This is also required for the injection of the manifest into the service worker by workbox
    // So despite it being outdate, Your application will not build without it
    const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST

    //Array for resources that have been cached by the service worker
    const cacheEntries = []

    //Run through the manifest and cache all resources
    const manifestURLs = manifest.map(
        (entry) => {
            //Create a new url using the service worker location and the manifest entry url
            const url = new URL(entry.url, self.location.href)

            cacheEntries.push(new Request(url.href, {
                credentials: data.credentials 
            }))

            return url.href
        }
    )

    // Cache resources when the service worker is first installed
    self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
        // The browser will wait until the promise is resolved
        event.waitUntil(
            // Open the cache and cache all the resources in it. This may include resources
            // that are not in the manifest
            caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
                return cache.addAll(cacheEntries)
            })
        )
    })

    // Upon activating the service worker, clear outdated caches by removing caches associated with 
    // URL resources that are not in the manifest URL array
    self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
        // - clean up outdated runtime cache
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {

                // clean up those who are not listed in manifestURLs since the manifestURLs are the only 
                // resources that are unlikely to be outdated
                cache.keys().then((keys) => {

                    keys.forEach((request) => {

                        data.debug && console.log(`Checking cache entry to be removed: ${request.url}`)

                        //If the manifest does not include the request url, delete it from the cache
                        if (!manifestURLs.includes(request.url)) {

                            cache.delete(request).then((deleted) => {
                                if (data.debug) {
                                    if (deleted)
                                        console.log(`Precached data removed: ${request.url || request}`)
                                    else
                                        console.log(`No precache found: ${request.url || request}`)
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        )
    })

    //Register all URLs that are found in the manifest and use the buildStrategy function to cache them
    registerRoute(
        ({ url }) => manifestURLs.includes(url.href),
        buildStrategy()
    )

    // Inform the service worker to send all routes that are not recognized to the network to be fetched
    setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly())

    // This method is called when the service worker is unable to fetch a resource from the network
    setCatchHandler(
        ({ event }) => {
            switch (event.request.destination) {
                case 'document':
                    return caches.match(data.fallback).then((r) => {
                        return r ? Promise.resolve(r) : Promise.resolve(Response.error())
                    })
                default:
                    return Promise.resolve(Response.error())
            }
        }
    )

    // this is necessary, since the new service worker will keep on skipWaiting state
    // and then, caches will not be cleared since it is not activated
    self.skipWaiting()
    clientsClaim()

    //Initialize Firebase and get the messaging module
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp)

    // //Handle Background Firebase Messages that come in while the app is closed
    onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
        console.log('Received background message ', payload)
    })

Honestly any help would be fantastic I've followed and re-written so many times following various tutorials to no avail...
